# Clicking an image button using selenium webdriver after login

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to automate a login page using selenium-webdriver and I'm using IE as the browser. The problem that I'm experiencing is that after the login I'm not able to select the image button. I have even introduced time delay after the login credentials are entered still the script runs and the button doesn't gets clicked. P.S I have commented all the methods I have tried too.

The code I have used is:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
            "C:/Program Files/IEDriverServer/IEDriverServer.exe");

    WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.navigate().to("website name");

    driver.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //driver.findElement(By.id("imgBtnAdd")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='Images/Go.gif']")).click(); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@ src='Images/Go.gif']")).click();
    //System.out.println("Manual Click of Ok button");
    //By xpath = By.xpath("//button[@name='imgBtnAdd'][@type='image'][contains(image(),'Images/Go.gif')]");
    //WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
      //.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));
    //myDynamicElement.click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='rblRoleGroup_4']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("imgBtnRoleGroup")).click();

    //WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("imgBtnAdd"));
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    //JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    //executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);        
    //driver.close();
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post a snippet of the web page source, HTML/JavaScript, around where the image is defined.

Comment: @Karthik most likely it is going to a new tab or window, so you need to tell your driver to switch to that tab or window

Comment: <input type="image" name="imgBtnAdd" id="imgBtnAdd" src="Images/Go.gif" style="border-width:0px;"> - the html source for the button @ProgrammersBlock

Comment: @CodingYoshi, do you mean that I have to provide the url of the next tab or window?

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: @Jose I am not getting any errors and the button is also not getting clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sendkkeys :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("imgBtnAdd")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

If image is in new window try this:

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())

{

driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it still doesn't gets clicked

Comment: The button is similar to the "compose email" button which appears after we login to the gmail

Answer (score 0):

After viewing your code, I have noticed that your `xpath` was wrong.

Instead of using `<img>` tag, use `<input>` tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@src='Images/Go.gif']")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `src` attribute of `<input>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I've tried this too still there is a problem clicking the button

Comment: Hello, You have not mentioned any click event inside your <input> tag. that's why it is not clickable.
Try to update your <input> tag with onclick attribute like this and then execute above mentioned code. it will work fine for sure. :)

<input type="image" name="imgBtnAdd" id="imgBtnAdd" src="Images/Go.gif" style="border-width:0px;" onclick="javascript:alert('hhhhhhhhh')">

Answer (score 0):

Try click using `JavascriptExecuter` might help you -

```
      WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.id("imgBtnAdd"));

      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
      js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks for the script but the button is not getting clicked without a manual mouse click

Comment: <input type="image" name="imgBtnAdd" id="imgBtnAdd" src="Images/Go.gif" style="border-width:0px;"